# How can I add a different static block to each paginated page in my catalog?

Tags: static-block, pagination

Right now I have a static block with content on each of my category catalog pages.

When users page through the paginated catalog results, the block is static and does not change content.

I would like to create say 3 or 4 static blocks per category, and assign them to the first 3 or 4 pages in the paginated results.

So page 1 would display static block 1. Clicking on page 2 would now display static block 2, and so on.

Is there a way to conditionally render static blocks based on the URL or path?

Comment: Good question! I'm afraid this will not be possible without a custom module though.